# I2C Addressing after device address is known

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, addressing

I have an I2C device that I know the address is 0x70 (probed when connected to Raspberry Pi using i2cdetect -y 1). My issue is that the bytes I want to look at need to be called in WiringPi. The output string is seven bytes long and WiringPi looks at the device address and then looks at the byte address I want to read. 
<del>That being said, would the addressing look like:</del>

Device Addr.= 0x70:
   First Byte Addr.= 0x01
----or----
   First Byte Addr.=0x71

Does the address need a 'new' address identification (starting from 1) or does the address number get 'appended' (yes, I use that loosely) to the device address?

---

New Information:
I found this documentation after sifting deeper:
[Upgrade Guide](https://www.sgxsensortech.com/content/uploads/2016/07/Customer-upgrade-guide-MiCS-VZ89TD-to-MiCS-VZ89TE.pdf)
and [Short Communication Guide](https://www.sgxsensortech.com/content/uploads/2017/03/I2C-Datasheet-MiCS-VZ-89TE-rev-H-ed170214-Read-Only.pdf)

It seems that from the upgrade sheet the slave's internal address for the address byte is **0xE0** for *write*. The command byte I want to use the command(#3.5): 0b000001100 (which I assume in hex is: **0x0C**). It then seems that the address byte for *read* is **0xE1**. From this point how would I read from the data bytes since their registers aren't explicitly shown (look at the Upgrade Guide)?

Here is my current code in WiringPi (C++):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>

using namespace std;

#define SLAVE_ADDR 0x70
#define DEV_ADDR_W 0XE0
#define DEV_ADDR_R 0XE1
#define DEV_COMMAND 0X0C //GET STATUS


int main(){
    int fd,writeRes,comm_res,readRes;
    fd=wiringPiI2CSetup(SLAVE_ADDR);
    cout<<"Initial Result: "<<fd<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
        writeRes=wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd,DEV_ADDR_W,0);
        cout<<"Write to Address(write): "<<writeRes<<endl;
        comm_res=wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd,DEV_COMMAND,0);
        cout<<"Slave Command Acknowledge: "<<comm_res<<endl;
        readRes=wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd,DEV_ADDR_R,0);
        cout<<"Write to Recieve Data: "<<readRes<<endl;
        int readD_1=wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,0x0D);
        cout<<"Data 1, VOC= "<<readD_1<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: 0x70? Is it an I²C mux?

Comment: @Janka, Unless Raspberry Pi explicity uses a multiplexer the answer is no. I'm still inexperienced with I2C on the hardware side.

Comment: What is the part number of the device you are trying to access?

Comment: It is made by SPEC Technologies, MiCS-VZ-89TE. [link](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/18/MiCS-VZ-89TE-V1.0-1100483.pdf)

Comment: Unfortunately, this sheet does not say anything about the I²C interface of that board. If I had that information, I could give you the correct C source code (approx 10 lines) you had to use. Why do you want to use WiringPi? Linux has built-in I²C support.

Comment: @Brandon  The datasheet for your sensor board leaves a lot to be desired - table of I2C registers, for instance.  I wouldn't design in a part with a poor datasheet like that.

Comment: Here https://www.pocketmagic.net/mics-vz-89-air-quality-sensor/ is a link with some code to access the board.  It looks like it uses repeated starts, which could be the cause of confusion.

Comment: Thank you all. I know the datasheet is horrific for addressing but that's what I have. I've looked at the pocketmagic sheet and I'm starting to make some ideas about what is going on.

Comment: That source code is very simple and clear. Repeated start is standard if you need to turn from write to read. You first have to write the address in write mode, then the register number, then repeated start, write the address tn read mode, the read all the data. That's how most I²C sensors work.

Comment: Also, @Janka, I'm using WiringPi because it gives me more flexibility when I integrate more modules into my system. I need to make sure the code plays nice with each module first then see if it works when they're all together.

Comment: I highly recommend pigpio over WiringPi.  Take a look at my answer here https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3627/is-there-an-i2c-library/31756#31756 for an example of how easy it is to do repeated starts

Comment: @BrandonWilliams - I can't help with your question regarding WiringPi as I don't use it (so not writing this as an answer) but there is a document for your device which *specifically* describes its I2C communication protocol (and the fact that there is a required delay). So if you haven't seen it yet, read this: [SGX VZ89TE I2C communication](https://www.sgxsensortech.com/content/uploads/2017/03/I2C-Datasheet-MiCS-VZ-89TE-rev-H-ed170214-Read-Only.pdf).

Comment: @Brandon  There is an IC on your sensor board.  What's the model of the IC?  Is that an off-the-shelf IC?  Or, is that an ASIC?

Comment: @NickAlexeev, I can't find that information. The print is too small to read as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved]
This module is a useful tool once you learn how to work with it. After emailing Gordon (from wiringPi), it was pointed out that I was trying to look too deep. Raspberry Pi took care of what I was worried about. Knowing that it took some trial and error to get addresses and commands correct but my following code seems to work before close calibration and testing for the CO2 sensitivity (note: the 'cout' output reading out the data buffer is off. But that's not too important right now):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>
#include <cerrno>

using namespace std;

const uint8_t dev_id = 0x70;
const uint8_t dev_addr = 0b000001100;
const uint8_t dev_comm = 0x0C;
const uint8_t dev_data = 0x00;

uint8_t getCRC(uint8_t bytes_to_send[6]){
    uint8_t byte_sum = 0x00;
    uint8_t crc;
    for(int i=0; i<6 ; i++){
        byte_sum += bytes_to_send[i];
    }
    crc = byte_sum;
    crc += (byte_sum/(0x0100));
    crc = 0xFF - crc;
    return crc;
}

int main(){
    int fd;
    int write_res;
    uint8_t sensor_data[8];
    int read_res;
    uint8_t crc;
    uint8_t out_buff[6]{dev_addr, dev_comm, dev_data, dev_data, 
        dev_data, dev_data};
    crc = getCRC(out_buff);
    cout<<"CRC: "<<(int)crc<<endl;
    uint8_t out_buff_full[7]{dev_addr, dev_comm, dev_data, dev_data, 
        dev_data, dev_data, 0xFF /*crc*/};
    if((fd=wiringPiI2CSetup(0x70)) < 0){
        cout<<"Error Occured in setting up Dev_ID: 0x70"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"FD= "<<fd<<endl;
        cout<<"-------------Before Writing, Check Sensor Array---------------"<<endl;
        read_res = read(fd, sensor_data, 8);
        cout<<"1: "<<(int)sensor_data[0]<<endl;
        cout<<"2: "<<(int)sensor_data[1]<<endl;
        cout<<"3: "<<(int)sensor_data[2]<<endl;
        cout<<"4: "<<(int)sensor_data[3]<<endl;
        cout<<"5: "<<(int)sensor_data[4]<<endl;
        cout<<"6: "<<(int)sensor_data[5]<<endl;
        cout<<"7: "<<(int)sensor_data[6]<<endl;
        cout<<"8: "<<(int)sensor_data[7]<<endl;
        cout<<"-------------End Test Before Write---------------"<<endl;
        if((write_res = write(fd, out_buff_full, 7)) != 7){
            cout<<"There could be an issue writing to the file."<<endl;
            cout<<"Write returned: "<<write_res<<endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            sleep(5);
            if((read_res = read(fd, sensor_data, 8)) != 8){
                cout<<"There could be an issue reading from the file."<<endl;
                cout<<"Read returned: "<<read_res<<endl;
                return 0;
            }
            else{
                cout<<"Returned Data {Address}: "<<(int)sensor_data[0]<<endl;
                cout<<"Returned Data {VOC}: "<<(int)sensor_data[1]<<endl;
                cout<<"Returned Data {CO2}: "<<(int)sensor_data[2]<<endl;
                cout<<"Returned Data {Raw Sensor Value[MSB]}: "<<(int)sensor_data[3]<<endl;
                cout<<"Returned Data {Raw Sensor Value}: "<<(int)sensor_data[4]<<endl;
                cout<<"Returned Data {Raw Sensor Value[LSB]}: "<<(int)sensor_data[5]<<endl;
                cout<<"Returned Data {Error Byte}: "<<(int)sensor_data[6]<<endl;
                cout<<"Returned Data {CRC}: "<<(int)sensor_data[7]<<endl;
            }
        close(fd);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code has been verified to work and solves my problem.

#### Lesson: Raspberry Pi is a full computer (even for comm. protocols) and you can't go too far down the rabbit hole, you'll get lost.

I just hope this helps anyone who may need it.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the follwing C source code, using the standard Linux I²C driver. The key is understanding the ioctl() parameter preparation. The complete I²C transfer is handled by the kernel driver automatically.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    struct i2c_msg i2c_msgs[2];
    struct i2c_rdwr_ioctl_data i2c_transfer;
    uint8_t rdata[6];
    int fd;

    /* Open I2C device. */
    fd = open("/dev/i2c-1", O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("i2c device open");
        return 2;
    }

    /* Select and read CO2 register. */
    i2c_msgs[0].addr   = 0x70;
    i2c_msgs[0].flags  = 0;
    i2c_msgs[0].len    = 1;
    i2c_msgs[0].buf    = "\x08";

    i2c_msgs[1].addr   = 0x70;
    i2c_msgs[1].flags  = I2C_M_RD;
    i2c_msgs[1].len    = 6;
    i2c_msgs[1].buf    = (char*)&rdata;

    i2c_transfer.msgs  = i2c_msgs;
    i2c_transfer.nmsgs = 2;

    if (ioctl(fd, I2C_RDWR, &i2c_transfer) < 0) {
        perror("i2c CO2 read");
        return 2;
    };

    /* Print result. */
    printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x\n", rdata[0], rdata[1], rdata[2], rdata[3], rdata[4], rdata[5]);

    /* Finish. */
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are we ignoring the 7th byte since you defined length of rdata array as 6?

Comment: The code on that site https://www.pocketmagic.net/mics-vz-89-air-quality-sensor/ says it's 6 bytes to read.

Comment: If you are confused, what the kernel driver does is *S,0x70WR, 0x08,S,0x70RD,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,P*

Comment: In the code, i get several errors. The first is the `struct i2c_msg i2c_msgs[2];` gets an error saying the array type has and incomplete element type. And secondly, did you mean something else than `I2C_M_RD` like something from [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/i2c-protocol)

Comment: Please add `#include <sys/ioctl.h>` and `#include <linux/i2c.h>` to the list of includes. Unfortunately, the explicit includes needed change with each API version.

Comment: After compilation, `./i2ctest2` (named it that with gcc -o) results in a `Segmentation Fault`

Comment: Hmm, that's unfortunate, because it works for me (with another chip at 0x50). Try running it with a debugger to find the culprit: `gdb ./i2ctest2`, then `run` at the gdb prompt.

Comment: It gave me warnings originally during compilation about "assignment from incompatible pointer type" for `i2c_transfer.msgs =i2c_msgs;`, could that be the issue?

Comment: If you recompiled it with the additional includes, it should compile with no warnings at all. Sometimes -std=c99 is required, this depends on the compiler you used. You did gcc this on the Raspi, didn't you? Because an x86 binary won't run on the Raspi.

Comment: Gcc filename.c -o exfilename

Comment: Maybe you are missing these include files in your installation? They belong to the *linux-libc-dev* package in Raspbian.